# For chrome extension, how can main.js call function from popup.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have extracted username and password(main.js) from webpages and try to store them in indexeddb(popup.js). So far, the popup.html(popup.js) can store username and password manually. I want to call the function in popup.js when there are username and password. Thank you very much.

Function in main.js

```
if (username && password)    
{            
    if(confirm("Store domain with username and password？"))      
    {        
        //want to call function test() from popup.js       
    }
    else
    {
    }    
}
```

Function in popup.js

```
function test()
{
    alert("function called");
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "PM Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "a Google Chrome extension",
  "permissions": ["tabs"],

  "browser_action": {  
    "default_icon": "icon.png" ,
    "default_title": "PM Extension",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", 
      "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "main.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }]
}
```

Comment: you can just call it as if where in the same file as long as it is included in the page (providing there is no other function called test() in which case you should look into namespacing)

Comment: Naming your files here is not enough. Please add your manifest so we can see how you use `main.js`.

Comment: @NING Comments are not suited for that. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## main.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('Your string/ object/ whatever', function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

## popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request === 'What I want to recieve') {
        // Do something
        sendResponse('A response');
    } 
});
```

See the [Massage Passing documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple).

Comment: Your code dump style answer can be much improved by including a link to relevant documentation.